# Delphi Embedded Chrome

Tags: delphi, google-chrome

is somebody experience on using delphi embedded chrome? [delphichromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).
how to make get accessed to its HTML DOCUMENTS? like assign a value to Editbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [demos\guiclient](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn/trunk/demos/guiclient) directory for an example.

Update: an example to set text of an input field on the [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig) page:

```
procedure TMainForm.actDomExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  q: ICefDomNode;
begin
  crm.Browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(
    procedure (const doc: ICefDomDocument)
    var
      q: ICefDomNode;
    begin
      // "q" is the ID of the text input element
      q := doc.GetElementById('q');
      if Assigned(q) then
        q.SetElementAttribute('value', 'Hello, world');
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: Nothing in there? Excuse me, what do you mean by that? There's source code, isn't there? Can't you see `TMainForm.actDomExecute` method in `main.pas`?

Comment: i cannot figure it out how to set value on it. It seems like you are just viewing what is inside. SetValue doesn't work or assigning a value does not reflect to the current page. any idea how?

Comment: @XBasic3000 See my example above.