# How to iterate DOM nodes in Delphi Chromium Embedded without use of anonymous method?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tchromium

[Delphi Embedded Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960721/delphi-embedded-chrome)

Due to my limited skill, I cannot figure out how to do the same thing in Delphi 7, as it doesn't support an anonymous method!

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TheProcThatHandlesItAll(const doc: ICefDomDocument)
var
  q: ICefDomNode;
begin
  // "q" is the ID of the text input element
  q := doc.GetElementById('q');
  if Assigned(q) then
    q.SetElementAttribute('value', 'Hello, world');
end

procedure TMainForm.actDomExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  crm.Browser.MainFrame.VisitDomProc(TheProcThatHandlesItAll);
end;
```