# DCEF3 TChromium : iterate the DOM and click buttons / fill inputs

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, twebbrowser, tchromium

Because Internet Explorer is dead, i'm in the (long) process to replace TWebbrowser by TChromium in all my applications.

With TWebbrowser we had a complete and well documented interface to access the DOM through the IHTMLElement interface.

Since DCEF3 documentation is nearly inexistent, i'm searching for examples of how to (if possible) iterate and manipulate the DOM in TChromium :

- Select / get an element's HTML source
- Click on a button
- Fill an input
- Focus a control

Is there an native interface to do it, or the only way is using javascript directly ?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865242/how-to-iterate-dom-nodes-in-delphi-chromium-embedded-without-use-of-anonymous-me

Comment: TWebBrowser is not dead

Answer (score 0):

realized through JS code (Fill an input):

```
if Assigned(Chromium.Browser) and Assigned(Chromium.Browser.Mainframe) then
begin
jsCode:= 'document.forms[0].quick_email.value="Email";';
Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(jsCode, 'about:blank', 0);

jsCode:= 'document.forms[0].quick_pass.value="Pass";';
Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(jsCode, 'about:blank', 0);

jsCode:= 'document.forms[0].submit();';
Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(jsCode, 'about:blank', 0);
end;
```